# how to manually create $this 2

Tags: jquery

I have function in JS that get the "$this".

I would like to use this function in another place. can i manually create "$this"?

please see the code:

```
function print_results(element) {
    var startRow    = element.attr("startRow"); 
    var maxRes      = element.attr("maxRes");   
}


$(document).on("click", ".moreItins-btn", function(){
    print_results($(this));
}); 

$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
$(this) = ....
print_results(HERE I WANT TO SENT THE SAME $THIS AS IN THE ABOVE CODE);
}
```

Comment: `this` is just a reference to the element that caused the event. If you want to get the `.moreItins-btn` element, use `$('.moreItins-btn');`. If you have multiple elements with that class then you will need to come up with a mechanism to determine which one you need - for example toggle a class on the element when it's clicked, then select by that class instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - oh, i thought that is some kind of array...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simple select that class

like

```
$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
var moreItinsObject = $('.moreItins-btn');
print_results(HERE I WANT TO SENT THE SAME $THIS AS IN THE ABOVE CODE);
//here moreItinsObject is same as that $this 
}
```

I thing it will help you.